# Add a scrollviewer to a contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I want to add a scrollviewer into my contextMenu because I can have a lot (30-40) of subitems.

So I added the scrollviewer in the submenuHeader Template :

```
<ControlTemplate 
  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" 
  TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" 
          BorderBrush="Pink"
          Background="Transparent"
           Cursor="Hand">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter 
        Name="Icon"
        Margin="6,0,6,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ContentSource="Icon"/>
                <ContentPresenter 
        Name="HeaderHost"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource CouleurTexteBouton}"
        Margin="5,2,2,2"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <Path 
        Grid.Column="3"
        Name="CheckMark"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z" 
        Fill="{StaticResource CouleurTexteBouton}" />
                <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Right"
        HorizontalOffset="10" 
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border 
          Name="SubmenuBorder"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Style="{StaticResource StyleBlocsPopUpWithBorder}"
          TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource CouleurTexteBouton}">
                        <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource FavsScrollViewer}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,5" MaxHeight="400">
                        <StackPanel  
            IsItemsHost="True" 
            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

The scrollviewer is working fine but the horizontal offset between each level is not working anymore if the parent has a scrollbar (my level 0 has only 7 items so doesn't have any scrollbar so the horizontal offset of the subitem works fine. But as you can see in the screen (left bloc is level 1 = subitems from my level 0, right bloc is level 2 of subitem and the horizontal offset isn't working due to the scrollbar.

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Here is the complete template/style of my contextmenu :

```
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
<Style x:Key="StyleContext" TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                    <Border 
                        Name="Border"
                        Width="Auto" >
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}"
       TargetType="Separator">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green"
                BorderThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- TopLevelHeader -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border"  Cursor="Hand">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter 
        Margin="6,3,6,3" 
                    Name="HeaderHost"
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                     />
                <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Bottom"
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border 
          Name="SubmenuBorder"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Background="Blue"
          BorderBrush="Yellow"
          BorderThickness="2" >
                        <StackPanel  
            IsItemsHost="True" 
            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- TopLevelItem -->
    <ControlTemplate 
  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" 
  TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border Name="Border" Cursor="Hand" >
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter        
        Margin="6,3,6,3" 
        ContentSource="Header"
                    Name="content_text"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- SubmenuItem 
    -->
    <ControlTemplate 
        x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
        TargetType="MenuItem"
        >
        <Border 
            Name="Border"
          BorderBrush="Transparent"
          Background="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter 
        Name="Icon"
        Margin="6,0,6,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ContentSource="Icon"/>
                <Border 
        Name="Check"  
        Width="13" Height="13" 
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Margin="6,0,6,0" 
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <Path 
          Name="CheckMark"
          Width="7" Height="7" 
          Visibility="Hidden" 
          SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
          StrokeThickness="2"
          Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter 
        Name="HeaderHost"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
        Margin="5,2,0,2"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Thank you

Comment: Could be a solution using a margin on the Template for the SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey , on the main Border.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is there a way to keep the contextmenu opened ? If so I could try to change "every" margin using Snoop

Comment: You can try the StayOpen property. Look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.staysopen.aspx

Comment: I found that the horizontalOffset could be used as a margin (margin values  are ignored ?) but I need to set my HorizontalOffset depending on the parent scrollviewer (if it is shown not), I can use a converter but I don't know how to find if the parent scrollviewer is visible ?